# What are options to install php5.6 after ubuntu trusty 14.04 reaches EOL

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, php-5.6

As the Ubuntu Trusty (14.04) reached [EOL](https://news.softpedia.com/news/ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr-reaches-end-of-life-on-april-30-2019-524835.shtml) last month, it seems one of the popular [ppa:ondrej/php](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) does not support php 5.6 on ubuntu trusty. Are there still other ways to add this support safely ?

Comment: Same issue with Ubuntu 14 and PHP7 via ondrej